# Installing a gpu card in a dell poweredge

Tags: graphics, vmware, virtualization, xen

Im trying to accomplish the same thing nvida does in their video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nyg2kZfF5A&noredirect=1 where they are able to play games streaming from the computer. Im not quite sure how they do this except from the fact that they use splashtop (I will be using vmware or xen). If anybody knows the configuration that would be great. I am going to try to accomplish this on a dell poweredge r200 quad-core xeon 3.0ghx with 8gb ram. But I would like to add the gaming capability to the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use Splashtop?

It's the best stream your desktop pieces of software out there.

You need to have the splashtop client on your computer and tablet. You can use a google account with splashtop to easily connect your devices.

I HIGHLY recommend instead of looking for "another" way, just go with the best way. If you want more info about splashtop and how to set it up comment and I will add to this answer.

If you are asking what kind of desktop do you need to be able to stream games to a tablet I need more details about your desktop.

Comment: I would like to use splashtop but do I have to configure the host to allow gaming graphics to render correctly?

Comment: Can the computer you have play the game? 
If so just log in remotely with splashtop. And from the remote device just launch the game.

Comment: ok, so if the computer can play the game splashtop will just display it. thanks I will try this out